# calling codeigniter controller through cron job

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

i am building a job portal using codeignitor and want to send daily job postings to the users and this is the command i am attempting to run in cron job

/usr/bin/php5 /home/sites/domain_name/public_html/beta/index.php cron index

where beta is the sub folder in the main public directory, cron is the controller name and index in the main method i want to call but it didnt work and i am getting this email (whole page html code in the email sample is below)

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie:ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%221ef765385e51654bcea0099cd2850232%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%220.0.0.0%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bb%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1434193382%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3BBA0%3A%22%22%3B%7Da8dfb8966c09414dc15b5160a7d7e65fc7ccebb0; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=gv78hetjs54rnjnhelb7rqeuklln6; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="check-mobile" class="visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="opcity">
<header>
<div id="header_sticky" class="header_wrap header">
    <div class="hdrbove_wrap">
       <div class="container">
                    <ul class="pull-right logout_rgist">
                    <li>
and soon on ....
```

Comment: With the default CodeIgniter settings it should work like this `http://localhost/beta/index.php/cron/index`

Comment: this is the path i want but how to specify the same thing with cron

Comment: Try to add `curl` or `wget` before the URL path

Comment: I'm using like that format: `/cron/index` so `/usr/bin/php5 /home/sites/domain_name/public_html/beta/index.php /cron/index`

Comment: i tried this too but didnt work